# error when I try to create a new repository in git on mac os sierra

Tags: git

I tried to create a new git repository after:

`git init`

this result's: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzTjY.png)

`-bash: test: on: integer expression expected
-bash: test: master: integer expression expected
-bash: test: _NO_REMOTE_TRACKING_: integer expression expected
-bash: test: ^: integer expression expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your repository creation worked just fine.  Whatever script(s) you are using that are intended to set your bash prompt based on your current Git repository, however, are hopelessly broken in the rare case that you are ever in a new, empty repository.

The brokenness is likely to go away once you create the first commit in that repository.  You could also try finding better bash scripts for setting prompts.

Comment: I already fix this, the problem was on git-extras, this extension causes a lot of problems. so I remove that. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used an old version of https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt (included inside my $HOME/.bashrc). After updating the gi-prompt the problem was gone.